# The object in change function is not defined for ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, input

I am attempting to the get value of an input element on change:

HTML:

```
<li><input type="number" id="point" value="<?php echo $game['point']; ?>"></li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#button-ajax').click(function(){
        var _pointObj = $('#point');

        _pointObj.bind('change', function(){
            var pointObj= $(this).val();
       });
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/league/ajax_call') ?>",
          dataType: "html",
          data: { 
            point: pointObj,
            isAjax: 1
            },
            success: function(result){
                $('#skeModal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

But I am getting following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: pointObj is not defined

What do you guys think I am doing someting wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: are you trying to do the ajax request on change of the input field or when then button is clicked

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am trying to post this value to a controller function when someButton is clicked via ajax (of course changed or not changed value of input by user)

Comment: then see my answer... there is no need for the change handler

Comment: yeah that would be a bunch of spaghetti code.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to sent the ajax request when the button is clicked with the value of the input field so

```
$(function () {
    $('#button-ajax').click(function () {
        var _pointObj = $('#point');

        var pointObj = _pointObj.val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/league/ajax_call') ?>",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
                point: pointObj,
                isAjax: 1
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#skeModal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

In your case the variable `pointObj` is local to the change callback method, but when the click handler is called then the variable is not declared that is the reason for error.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is out of scope. You declare `pointObj` inside a handler, then attempt to use that variable outside the handler. It is also important to note that this handler is being bound on a button click, so changing the value previous to clicking this button will NOT trigger the change event.

In short, declare your variable 1 level higher:

```
var pointObj;

_pointObj.bind('change', function(){
        pointObj= $(this).val();
   });
```

If your simply trying to get the value of the `select` element on button click, use `val()`

```
var currentPoint = $("#point").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other folks had mentioned, you've got a scope issue with your pointObj declaration. You could also write it like this if you wanted the click and change event on the input field. In Addition, you are trying to bind the change event inside the click event.

```
    // Generic Function to call for each. 
function updatePoints() {

    $('#button-ajax').attr('disabled', true);

    var pointObj = $('#point').val(),
        data = {
            point: pointObj,
            isAjax: 1
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.someurl.com",
        dataType: "html",
        data: data,
        error: function(status) {
            // console.log(status);
            $('#button-ajax').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }).done(function(){
        $('#skeModal').modal('hide');
    });
}

$(function () {

    // Bind Your Click of the Button
    $('#button-ajax').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        updatePoints();
    });

    // Bind your change event for the input
    $('#point').change(function(){
        updatePoints();
    });

});
```